# Handling char* with node-ffi

Tags: c++, node.js, ffi, node-ffi

I am using node-ffi to load a library and call a function that returns a char*, the pointer being created inside the shared library.

Do I need to create a matching function that can delete the buffer? e.g.

**main.cpp**

```
char* get_error()
{
    char* buf = new char[25];
    buf[24] = '\0';
    return buf;
}

void delete_buffer( char* buf )
{
    delete[] buf;
}
```

**test.js**

```
var libTest = ffi.Library( 'libtest', {
    'get_error': [ 'string', [] ],
    'delete_buffer': [ 'void', [ 'string' ] ]
});

var test = libTest.get_error();
libTest.delete_buffer( test );
```

When I tried this, I got a segfault. Does node-ffi automatically create a copy? How am I supposed to do this correctly?

Comment: I can't reproduce segfault with your code. As for me, everything looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did more testing and I stopped getting segfaults as well. I think my original issue was with something inside my library.